# Regular expression [0-99]p/sec

Tags: c#, regex

A part of my application requires to find out the occurrence of "1p/sec" or "22p/sec" or     "22p/ sec" or ( [00-99]p/sec also [00-99]p/ sec) in a string.

so far I am able to get only the first occurrence(i.e if its a single digit, like the one in the above string). I should be able to get 'n' number of occurrence

Someone pl provide guidance

```
string input = "US Canada calling @ 1p/ sec (Base Tariff - 11p/sec). Validity : 30 Days.";

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d)[p/sec]",
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

     //   input.IndexOf("p/sec");

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, but it appears that you want to say `@"\d{1,2}p/sec"`.

Comment: Or simpler `@"\d\dp/sec"`

Comment: sorry about it. Let me just give te data for which it should work  `1p/sec, 1p/ sec, 93p/sec ` also it should be able to find more than one occurrence of the expression in a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *quantify* your `\d` in the regex, for example by adding a `+` quantifier, which will then cause `\d+` to match at least one but possibly more digits. To restrict to a specific number of digits, you can use the `{n,m}` quantifier, e.g. `\d{1,2}` which will then match either one or two digits.

Note also that `[p/sec]` as you use it in the regex is a character class, matching a single character from the set { `c`, `e`, `p`, `s`, `/` }, which is probably not what you want because you'd want to match the `p/sec` *literally*.

A more robust option would probably be the following

```
(\d+)\s*p\s*/\s*sec
```

which a) matches `p/sec` literally and also allows for whitespace between the number and the unit as well as around the `/`.

Comment: I think he needs to match one or two (00-99).

Comment: While they do say so, I guess `+` is the safer choice, because they would otherwise get the wrong result with things like 123p/sec.

Comment: If that is supposed to match, yes indeed.

Comment: '    string input = "US Canada calling @ 1p/ sec (Base Tariff - 11p/sec). Validity : 30 Days.";

            // Here we call Regex.Match.
            MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+)\s*p\s*/\s*sec",
                RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

         //   input.IndexOf("p/sec");


            foreach (Match matchs in match)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(matchs.Groups[0].Value);
            }
'

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d{1,2})p/sec" ...
```

instead.

\d mathces a single digit. If you append {1,2} to that you instead match one - two digits. \d* would match zero or more and \d+ would match one or more. \d{1,10} would match 1-10 digits.

If you need to know if it was surrounded by brackets or not you could do

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(([\d{1,2}])|(\d{1,2}))p/sec"
...
bool hasBrackets = match.Groups[1].Value[0] == '[';
```

Comment: With `@"(\d{1,2})p/sec"` you will also get a partial match on e.g. "12345p/sec" (The group would contain 45)

Comment: Yes, that is true. The accepted answer has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
^\[?\d\d?\]?/\s*sec$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

^\[?\d\d?\]?/\s*sec$

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[?                      '[' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d?                      digits (0-9) (optional (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]?                      ']' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  sec                      'sec'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you want to find *all* occurrances, right? Use a matchcollection

```
string input = "US Canada calling @ 1p/sec (Base Tariff - 11p/sec). Validity : 30 Days.";

// Here we call Regex.Match.
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d){1,2}[p/sec]", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(input);
//   input.IndexOf("p/sec");

// Here we check the Match instance.
foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
     Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string input = "US Canada calling @ 1p/ sec (Base Tariff - 11p/sec). 91p/ sec , 123p/ sec Validity : 30 Days.";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b(\d{1,2})p/\s?sec");

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   11
>   91

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), to anchor the match to the start of a "word" (**notice that it will not match the "123p/ sec" in the test string!**)

`\d{1,2}` Will match one or two digits. [See Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

`p/\s?sec` matches a literal "p/sec" with an optional whitespace before "sec"

Answer (score 0):

Regex Expression:

```
((?<price>(\d+))p/sec)|(\[(?<price>(\d+[-]\d+))\]p/sec)
```

In C# you need to run a for loop to check multiple captures:

```
if(match.Success)
{
   for(int i = 0; i< match.Groups["price"].Captures.Count;i++)
   {
            string key = match.Groups["price"].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(key);
   }
}
```